# WHERE statement in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Just wondering what the correct way of structuring statements like this is?

```
 @products = Product.where('release_date <= ?', Date.today AND 'physical_status' == 'active')
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is this:

```
@products = Product.where('release_date <= ? AND physical_status = ?', Date.today, 'active')
```

You can take a look at this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks, no errors now but also got no results. However, I figured out that the search on 'active' is case sensitive, entries in DB are 'Active'. So it is working but didn't expect case to be an issue. Many thanks.

Comment: you can use `LOWER(?)` in the query